# How to build password protection using php password_hash and password_verify

Tags: php, security, password-protection

I have some problem understanding how to use php 5.5.0+ password_hash and password_verify to protect pages access.

Let me explain what I did.
1) When I create a new user for my webapp, I store username and hashed password in a users table. To hash the password before to store it in the db, I use

```
$hashedp = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

2) On page login I can take the password submitted by the user in the form and 'compare' it with that stored in the database for the same user in this way

```
$password = the password submitted by the user
$user_hashedp = the hashed password taken from the db
if (password_verify($password, $user_hashedp)) {
    // login the user
} else {
    // show error
}
```

3) What I don't understand is how I can check and protect access to other pages, after the user has logged in. Imagine You have another page page1.php that you want to show only if the user is logged correctly.
How can I build this check?

kind regards,
Matt

Comment: This is what you use sessions for

Answer (score 3):

Like already said in the comments you can use session for this. Below an example.

```
session_start();
if (password_verify($password, $user_hashedp)) {
    // login the user
    // create session for logged in user.
    $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['authorized'] = false;
    // show error
}
```

Then in authorizedusersonly.php:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['authorized'] === true) {
 //content for authorized users
} else {
 //content for unauthorized users
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to first ask whether the variable really exists: `if (isset($_SESSION['authorized']) && ($_SESSION['authorized'] === true))...`, this would avoid warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how late I am to the party, but Daan has the right idea with **doing sessions.**

I would **personally set a username session variable upon a successful login**, then on **every** page, make sure that it is set. If it isn't, **redirect them** to a certain page, e.g. a login.

```
if (password_verify($password, $user_hashedp)) {
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user; // user being the login username; also verified.
} else {
    echo "Invalid credentials!"; // Throw some type of error. That's up to you.
}
```

On each page, you can either **include a file that will house the session verification code**, or just **copy/paste it onto every one of your pages**, like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["user"])) // If the user has not been verified...
    header("Location: login.php"); // Redirect them to a page of your choice, i.e. a login.
```

You could do it the other way, but the greatest advantage you'd have with this is the fact that if you ever need to **obtain the username for something**, instead of having to get the **username through a query**, which might affect performance, you could simply **reference the session variable** and deal with it from there.

That is how I would personally do it.

Comment: Why stop there, you can use a JSON string as value, then decode it and use it  like `$user->id`